Set the width of the cells, using itext 7
I hope you can help me, I am looking to be able to set the width of the cells, I am using itext 7. If the string does not have space, itext puts all the text on a single line and does not add a line break to respect the width indicated.
       for(String columnName : columNames) {
            Paragraph paragraphCell = new Paragraph(columnName);
            paragraphCell.setFont(font);
            paragraphCell.setFontSize(10);
            paragraphCell.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
            Cell celda1 = new Cell();
            celda1.add(paragraphCell);
            **celda1.setWidth(25);** //Here I try to set the size, it does not respect the instruction
            table.addHeaderCell(celda1);
        }


Set the column size for all the columns at the time of initializing the table.
  int numColumns = columNames.size();
         
  float [] columnWidths = new float[numColumns};   
  Arrays.fill(columnWidths, 25);

  Table table = new Table(columnWidths); 

References:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/itext/itext_adding_table.htm
https://javadoc.io/doc/com.itextpdf/layout/7.0.1/com/itextpdf/layout/element/Table.html#Table-float:A-

I appreciate your help, I cannot solve my need 100%, however, I reviewed the article you share and I was finally able to solve it with the following code fragment that I share in case it could be of use to someone.
 List<String> columNames = getColumnNames(report);
    float [] pointColumnWidths = new float[columNames.size()];   
    for(int i=0; i< columNames.size(); i++){
       pointColumnWidths[i]= 50f;
    }
    Table table = new Table(pointColumnWidths, true); 

